# How to correctly set request headers in puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, puppeteer, request-headers, anti-bot

Let me start off by saying I know how to actually intercept, change, and send headers correctly, but I am very unsure of what order they should be in. If trying to bypass antibots like Data Dome, how can I cover up my tracks and make sure, for example: If I set my User Agent to something like: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36. That Data Dome can not tell I am 'lying' about my chrome version or anything other http headers? I'd like to know how I can make sure they think I am telling the truth, also can they tell by looking at TLS fingerprinting, Tcp/Ip fingerprinting, http2 fingerprinting, etc. That it does not match the headers I send?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.